# Wordpress amend postmeta after post creation

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom post type for properties and a front-end form for submitting them. The `post_type` in `wp_posts` is `property`.

There is a meta key in the `wp_postmeta` table called `REAL_HOMES_property_id`. Currently this is a textbox which accepts user input.

What I am trying to do is hide the field (already done), and populate this with the `ID` from `wp_posts`, when the form is submitted.

Is there a hook which will work on the `wp_postmeta` table after submission?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paste below code in your theme's functions.php file:

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'set_post_meta_func');
function set_post_meta_func($post_id)
{
    /* return if not porpoerty post */
    $post_type = get_post_type($post_id);
    if ( "property" != $post_type ) 
        return;

    /* return if revision */
    if(wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ))
        return;

    /* return if not published */
    if("publish" != get_post_status($post_id))
        return;

    // unhook this function so it doesn't loop infinitely
    remove_action( 'save_post', 'set_post_meta_func' );
    // update the post, which calls save_post again
    update_post_meta($post_id, "REAL_HOMES_property_id", "your value here");
    // re-hook this function
    add_action( 'save_post', 'set_post_meta_func' );
}
```

replace "your value here" with your value which you want to save.
Hopes it will help you!

Answer (score 1):

```
function assign_property_id( $post_id ) {

    $post_type = get_post_type($post_id);

    if($post_type == 'property') {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'REAL_HOMES_property_id', $post_id );
    }

}
add_action( 'save_post', 'assign_property_id' );
```

Comment: But actually what is the purpose of saving that same value in multiple locations ? I mean, what's the purpose to save in an external table the value of the current post ID ? This is too weird. Can you please explain further ? Maybe we can help you to get a better decision :)

Comment: @MerianosNikos I agree it is weird! The theme I am using does this, and outputs the property id in the front end rather than the post id. I figured this was the quickest way, rather than going through a bunch of theme files to see where property id is used.